# JavaScript not working correctly in content created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have [this number input jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/User-Friendly-Number-Input-Spinner-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html) included in my project. It's working correctly on default HTML content, but when I'm creating table rows with jQuery it's not working. There should be jQuery number input but instead that there is regular HTML5 number input.

How I'm calling function `bootstrapNumber()`

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-number-input.js"></script>
<script>
    $("input[type='number']").bootstrapNumber();
</script>
```

This is how the row is created by jQuery

```js
var row = '<tr id="product' + value.ID + '"><td>' + value.name + '</td>'
            + '<td class="text-right"><input class="form-control" type="number" value="1" min="0" />' + value.unit + '</td>'
            + '<td class="text-right">' + value.price + ' ' + value.currency + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle example?

Comment: I think you need call again `$("input[type='number']").bootstrapNumber();` after created new inputs

Comment: Can you provide the function which uses row variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because you call the `.bootstrapNumber()` only once in the start of your code. You need to call it every time you add a row to your table with jQuery.

```
<script>
    function addRowToTable(value) {
        var row = '<tr id="product' + value.ID + '"><td>' + value.name + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-right"><input class="form-control" type="number" value="1" min="0" />' + value.unit + '</td>'
                + '<td class="text-right">' + value.price + ' ' + value.currency + '</td></tr>';

        //add row to table here

        $("input[type='number']").bootstrapNumber(); //call the plugin again to make the new input of a bootstrapNumber input
    }
</script>
```

Also, if you at the load of the page already have some inputs you need to add this to - please remember to not just write the

```
$("input[type='number']").bootstrapNumber();
```

at the beginning of the script, you have to wrap it in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='number']").bootstrapNumber();
});
```

to not manipulate the DOM before the DOM has been loaded.

Comment: No problem. Please see my edit about the initial `bootstrapNumber()` call aswell. It may help you further on :-)